# Unable to play video in JSP Using JBOSS server

Tags: jsp, servlets

i am unable to play video songs using JSP page, i think there is root problem, 
i am getting video files from local drive at run time.

please guide me what steps i have to do to solve my problem

```
<div id="videoDiv"> <video id="video1" src="d:/temp/${con.content }" type="video/mp4" width="20%" controls> </video> </div>
```

Well i am not getting video file from my local drives but when
i store video at webcontent folder of my project it works.
but i am unable to get video from outside of my project

Comment: Show your code. The description is too vague.

Comment: you can't read from local file storage. put the file from where server can read it. how will it work when you site is live? [Read](http://www.coderanch.com/t/289980/JSP/java/retrieving-file-local-disk)

Comment: Finally done solved my problem 
Now i am able to play video from local drive using Servlet's and HTML 5 video tag

thank's for every one.